# Object item not updating after being updated from inside a fetch call

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fetch

i have a object that i want to update the 'marketBuyPrice' and 'marketSellPrice' entries for using data from a fetch call as follows:

```
//The object
const ores = {
  Hemorphite :{ name: 'Hemorphite', marketRef: '1231', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Veldspar :{ name: 'Veldspar', marketRef: '1230', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
};

//The fetch call
   function getMarketPrices(oreType, id) {
    var marketUrl = 'https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid='+id+'&usesystem=30000142';
    fetch(marketUrl)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(str => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {

            var buyPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var sellPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                
            //This is where the buy / sell prices get updated
            ores[oreType].marketBuyPrice = buyPrice;
            ores[oreType].marketSellPrice = sellPrice;

        })
   }
```

This works if i then view the entire array using:

```
console.log(ores);
```

Which returns:

```
{Hemorphite: {…}, Veldspar: {…}}
Hemorphite: {name: "Hemorphite", marketRef: "1231", marketBuyPrice: "1004.87", marketSellPrice: "1678.93"}
Veldspar: {name: "Veldspar", marketRef: "1230", marketBuyPrice: "12.00", marketSellPrice: "20.70"}
```

However if i try to view the specific updated entry:

```
console.log(ores[oreType].marketBuyPrice);
```

it returns it as empty as if it hasnt been updated yet when viewing the entire object as above it shows it as updated.

Could anyone offer any insight as to why this may be please.

Many thanks

```
//Update
const ores = {
  Hemorphite :{ name: 'Hemorphite', marketRef: '1231', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: '', refines: {isogen: '2.4', nocxium: '9'} },
  Veldspar :{ name: 'Veldspar', marketRef: '1230', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
};

const minerals = {
  Hemorphite :{ name: 'Hemorphite', marketRef: '1231', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: '',},
  Veldspar :{ name: 'Veldspar', marketRef: '1230', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: '',},
};

    function getMarketPrices(oreType, id) {
    var marketUrl = 'https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid='+id+'&usesystem=30000142';
    fetch(marketUrl)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(str => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {

            var buyPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var sellPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                
            ores[oreType].marketBuyPrice = buyPrice;
            ores[oreType].marketSellPrice = sellPrice;

        })
   }    

        console.log(ores);
        console.log((ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice));
```

Comment: You better use EVE api straight: https://esi.evetech.net/ui/. Evemarketeer is separate project. Write me in Telegram @aka_darth, i'll help you at all

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you forgot await:

```js
//The object
const ores = {
  Veldspar :{ name: 'Veldspar', marketRef: '1230', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
};

//The fetch call
function getMarketPrices(oreType, id) {
  var marketUrl = 'https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid='+id+'&usesystem=30000142';
  fetch(marketUrl)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(str => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
      .then(data => {
          var buyPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          var sellPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

          //This is where the buy / sell prices get updated
          ores[oreType].marketBuyPrice = buyPrice;
          ores[oreType].marketSellPrice = sellPrice;
      })
  }

getMarketPrices('Veldspar', '1230');
// data not updated now..
console.log(1, ores); 
console.log(2, ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice); 
// But when you open this object in chrome console, you see prices.
```

If you are logging primitives, console show you actual value at moment, but in modern browsers objects can be filled with data, which coming after object was logged to console:

[image]

Fixed:

```js
(async () => {

//The object
const ores = {
  Veldspar :{ name: 'Veldspar', marketRef: '1230', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
};

//The fetch call
async function getMarketPrices(oreType, id) {
  var marketUrl = 'https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid='+id+'&usesystem=30000142';
  await fetch(marketUrl)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(str => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
      .then(data => {
          var buyPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          var sellPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

          //This is where the buy / sell prices get updated
          ores[oreType].marketBuyPrice = buyPrice;
          ores[oreType].marketSellPrice = sellPrice;
      })
}


await getMarketPrices('Veldspar', '1230');
console.log(1, ores); 
console.log(2, ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice); 
// data updated.

  
})();
```

Ok, loop:

```js
(async () => {

//The object
const minerals = {
  Veldspar :{ name: 'Veldspar', marketRef: '1230', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Tritanium :{ name: 'Tritanium', marketRef: '34', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Pyerite :{ name: 'Pyerite', marketRef: '35', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Mexallon :{ name: 'Mexallon', marketRef: '36', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Isogen :{ name: 'Isogen', marketRef: '37', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Nocxium :{ name: 'Nocxium', marketRef: '38', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Zydrine :{ name: 'Zydrine', marketRef: '39', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
  Megacyte :{ name: 'Megacyte', marketRef: '40', marketBuyPrice: '', marketSellPrice: ''},
};

//The fetch call
async function getMarketPrices(type, id) {
  var marketUrl = 'https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid='+id+'&usesystem=30000142';
  await fetch(marketUrl)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(str => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
      .then(data => {
          var buyPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          var sellPrice = data.getElementsByTagName("percentile")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

          //This is where the buy / sell prices get updated
          minerals[type].marketBuyPrice = buyPrice;
          minerals[type].marketSellPrice = sellPrice;
      })
}

await Promise.all(
  Object.entries(minerals)
    .map(([name_double, {name, marketRef}]) =>
      getMarketPrices(name, marketRef)
    )
);
console.log(minerals); 


})();
```

Comment: I think you _also_ forgot the `await`

Comment: @Jamiec I am not forgot. I omit.

Comment: @Jamiec Dont worry, I added the snippet with await for you)

Comment: It's not for me, it's to actually answer the question! That's kind of the point of SO.

Comment: @Jamiec The actual question is `offer any insight as to why this may be please.`, so i dont need await for explain what happens

Comment: Hmmmm this isnt working for me when copying and pasting i still get the same result

Comment: @Dgeorgex000000 Snippet up here is working. I press run, i see prices. Dont you? Or what do you mean by "working"?

Comment: @Darth The point was that i could alway see the correct infomation when console logging the entire object : console.log(ores);  but couldnt when looking for the added item specifically: console.log(ores[oreType].marketBuyPrice); and i think the answer above still produces the same outcome

Comment: @Dgeorgex000000 Are you sure that your `oreType` is updated when you log it? You call it before call `getMarketPrices` function? you call `getMarketPrices` with same oreType? Show your code, my psychic is on vacation

Comment: @Darth i posted an //update on the end of my original post copy and paste that and you will see what i mean logging the whole object shows the prices updated but logging specifically the price shows it as empty stll

Comment: @Dgeorgex000000 yep, now i see. You really forgot `await`.

Comment: @Dgeorgex000000 I add your `console.log(ores[oreType].marketBuyPrice)` to both snippets

Comment: @Darth i see your answer works but the part where it calls the get marketprice function is actually nseted inside a function in my code that i removed for the sake of simplicity its actually being calls iside a each() function so the code in the answer u provided above wont work because the await needs to be top level :
`
   $('.ores-wrapper .ore').each(function(){
  await getMarketPrices(oreType, marketId);
     console.log(ores);
  console.log((ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice));
   });`

Any ideas how i could get around this?

Comment: ```$('.ores-wrapper .ore').each(
async /* !!! */
function(){ await getMarketPrices(oreType, marketId); console.log(ores); console.log((ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice)); });```

Comment: The above returns empty for the prices (Thanks for your help btw its apprecited):

$('.ores-wrapper .ore').each( async /* !!! */ function(){ await getMarketPrices('Veldspar', '1230'); console.log(ores); console.log((ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice)); });

Comment: And one more thing - you have a loop, but for each iteration you use same `oreType`..

Comment: Try to iterate the `ores` object and up each ore using right `oreType` keys at start a whole script

Comment: The each loop works but i removed some of it for clarity but if i manually pass in the variables it still returns the price as empty inside the loop but your code above where its not in a loop works 

```
//This works
await getMarketPrices('Veldspar', '1230');
console.log(1, ores); 
console.log(2, ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice); 
// data updated.


//This doesnt
$('.ores-wrapper .ore').each( async /* !!! */ function(){ await getMarketPrices('Veldspar', '1230'); console.log(ores); console.log((ores['Veldspar'].marketBuyPrice)); });
```

Comment: @Dgeorgex000000 I add the third snippet with loop for minerals.